# How to find device in /dev

Tags: centos, debian, qemu, udev

I have added a new virtual pci device to my debian6 VM (Virtual Machine).
I can see the device via "lspci" command, but I cannot find it in /dev.

Is it because it's not installed properly or it needs additional drivers or I just can't find the name?

lspci result:
00:08.0 Communication controller: Red Hat, Inc Virtio console

It works find in centos6, but I cannot find it in centos5 or debian6. (I have tested these OSes so far)

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @Downvoter(s): Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

The virtio serial console should appear as `/dev/hvc0`, if you don't have any other virtio serial ports defined for the virtual machine. If so, the number at the end for them may be something other than `0`.

Comment: @Jobin If you have a question, you should click the Ask Question button above. This is not a discussion forum.

Comment: Sorry for that. Posted: http://serverfault.com/questions/571281/why-is-there-a-socket-interface-on-the-host-and-a-character-device-interface-on